# Periodic Stream with debounceTime emits nothing

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, rxdart

I have a periodic stream that emits every second. I want to reduce the emit frequency with `debounceTime` of two seconds, so I can get something like: `[2, 4, 6 ...]`, but instead I get no events.

```
Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (count) => '$count')
  .debounceTime(Duration(seconds: 2))
  .listen(print); // prints nothing
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is working as expected: the events are emitted every second but debounce time is 2 seconds - if events stopped for more that 2 seconds you would see the last emmited value on the logs - see https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/DebounceExtensions/debounceTime.html for more info

Comment: most likely what you want is https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/ThrottleExtensions/throttleTime.html